# how to use tweepy to tweet a variable

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm using jupyter notebook to make a code that reads a trump tweets database and trains to make its own tweets based on the ones on the db. I want to use tweepy to tweet the output however I can't seem to find a way to tweet it.

I tried adding the status update command at the end of the code

```
def generate_w_seed2(sentence,diversity):
sentence = sentence[0:maxlen]
generated = ''
generated += sentence

sys.stdout.write(generated)

for i in range(120):
    x_pred = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        x_pred[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

    preds = modelo.predict(x_pred, verbose=0)[0]
    next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
    next_char = indices_char[next_index]

    generated += next_char
    sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char

    sys.stdout.write(next_char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
print()
return 
for s in random.sample(list(text),1):
    for diversity in [0.5]:
        generate_w_seed2(s,diversity)
    print()
    api.update_status(generate_w_seed2(s,diversity))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TweepError: [{'code': 170, 'message': 'Missing required parameter: status.'}]
```

I have also tried placing the variable in a function (named estado) and while it didn't read the variable it tweeted the following:

```
<function estado at 0x00000000E59DC6A8>
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the return value of `generate_w_seed2(s,diversity)` to see what it is?

Comment: `generate_w_seed2(s,diversity)` prints out the text generated by the trained model

Comment: right, but do you know what is returned when you call the function?